# An interpretation error for a python multithreading and multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I want to compare multithreading and multiprocessing python program. But, I got interpretation error:

File "./parallelPython.py", line 23
    time fornorm(g,range(100))
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

The code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -tt

import numpy as np
import math

def f(x):
    print x
    y = [1]*10000000
    [math.exp(i) for i in y]
def g(x):
    print x
    y = np.ones(10000000)
    np.exp(y)

from handythread import foreach
from processing import Pool
from timings import f,g

def fornorm(f,l):
for i in l:
    f(i)

time fornorm(g,range(100))
time fornorm(f,range(10))
time foreach(g,range(100),threads=2)
time foreach(f,range(10),threads=2)
p = Pool(2)
time p.map(g,range(100))
time p.map(f,range(100))
```

I do not why fornorm() has a problem, it has been defined !!!

thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an Indentation error here :

```
def fornorm(f,l):
for i in l:
    f(i)
```

After your def python is expecting an indented block.

By the way, `time something` is an IPython "magic" function and it won't work in a script file.  You should `import timeit` module and use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't say `fornorm` hasn't been defined, it says you have a syntax error on the line where you're calling `fornorm`. Syntax errors mean Python can't even understand your code: it's as if I say to you "flrk ask web ski ur lkjq", and then ask you to do what I said. An error about `fornorm` not being defined would happen much later. As it is, Python can't even tell whether you're asking it to call a function, let alone whether you're calling one that is already defined or not.

It looks like your error is this:

```
time fornorm(g,range(100))
```

That looks like you're trying to use the shell command `time`. Shell commands are not Python, and Python doesn't understand it.

However, your code as pasted into SO also has indentation errors, which should have triggered a syntax error earlier than that line, so I suspect what we can see here is not exactly what you were running.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting "time" from?  That's not a valid python statement.  It's not like shell scripting.

If you want to time stuff, use the timeit library:
http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html